# Can this select query be optimized more on a mobile device?

Tags: c#, optimization, sqlite, windows-mobile, mobile

We have a C# mobile application with SQLite database.
We are having a larger inventory database, such as 30k or 100k items. The database file is 12MB on a flash memory card.

Running a simpler SELECT query with limit takes 10-15 seconds.

```
select id,invitem,invid,cost from inventory 
   where itemtype = 1 and 
   (invitem like '%5204d%' or invid like '%5204d%') 
   limit 25
```

sometimes a category is involved too,

```
select id,invitem,invid,cost from inventory 
   where itemtype = 1 and 
   categoryid=147 and 
   (invitem like '%5204d%' or invid like '%5204d%')  
   limit 25
```

Indexes are created on:

```
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_inventory_categoryid ON " + this.TableName + " (categoryid);";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_inventory_itemtype ON " + this.TableName + " (itemtype);";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_inventory_invitem ON " + this.TableName + " (invitem);";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Those two fields in Like are VARCHAR, the others are NUMERIC.

Can this select query be optimized more on a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the initial % in your where..like clause. The index cannot be used in theis query, so a table scan is the only way it can be done. Adding the category id will help - at least it can use that inxdex.

Comment: I can remove the initial % for the second field `invid like '5204d%'`

Comment: that might help - the query optimizer might be able to use the index on invid to narrow down the possible matches before applying the invitem filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to check whether the indices are actually used. I would guess that the wildcard at the beginning of `like '%5204d%'` disables any use of indices on `invitem`.

Comment: I can remove the initial % for the second field `invid like '5204d%'`. How can I use this Explain in c# code? I do not have a SQLite console for Windows Mobile.

Comment: I'd guess you can just submit the query with EXPLAIN prepended and you get back a resultset whose contents do describe the query. You can also could copy the sqlite db to your desktop and analyse it there. Or at least a file with the same schema and data.